# extracting N from lme summary

Tags: r, summary, mixed-models

I'm looking for a quick way to pull out the number of observations (`N`) generated in the summary of a `lme` test, instead of copying and pasting? I found [this](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/trunk/R/texreg.R?view=markup&revision=28&root=texreg) online but the command doesn't appear to be built-in and the `texreg` package isn't uploaded to this site.

```
n <- nobs(model) #extract number of observations
```

Many thanks.

Comment: `library(nlme); fm1 <- lme(distance ~ age, data = Orthodont); nobs(fm1); nobs(summary(fm1))` works just fine for me...

Comment: I'm still getting the same error with nobs: : could not find function "nobs." I'm running v 2.12.1. Do you think it's a version thing?

Comment: It wasn't a problem previously, hehe.

Comment: @AWC Be aware that it's going to become difficult even installing packages, as the internal mechanisms of R changed rather profoundly in the versions 2.14 and 2.15, not to mention that due to the compiling of many base functions the current R is quite a lot faster than the dinosaur you're working with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(nlme)

x <- 1:80
g <- sort(rep(c(1,2,3,4),20))
set.seed(1)
y <- 3*x+g*0.01+rnorm(80,sd=0.01)

plot(y~x)
fit <- lme(y~x,random=~1|g)

nobs(fit)
[1] 80 #works just fine

fit$dims$N
[1] 80 #alternative
```